# Stretch an element of unknown width alongside elements of fixed width inside parent of unknown width

Tags: html, css

I have a parent `div` of unknown width (the width depend on some screen width calculations). The number of the child `div`s is 4 and are floated so that they are horizontally aligned. The 1st, 2nd and 4th are good candidates for fixed width value. However, the 3rd element can stretch to fit the remaining space in the parent `div`.

I don't know why the approach of `display:table;` for parent and `display:table-cell` for children didn't work for me. The three element's width is fixed except for the concerned div where I also tried `width:auto` to no avail.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
    <div class="third"></div>
    <div class="fourth"></div>
</div>
```

**A minimal CSS:**

```
.parent
{
  width: 100%;
  display:table;
}
.first
{
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
  display: table-cell;
}

.second
{
 width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
  display: table-cell;
}

.third
{

  height: 80px;
  float: left;
  display: table-cell;
}

.fourth
{
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Your usual help is much appreciated.

Comment: can you post also the HTML?

Comment: @silviagreen, thank you for your time, please to loook at my edit.

Comment: Go look into flexbox, that should make this rather trivial.

Comment: @CBroe, thank you sir. yes it seems flexbox is the answer to this issue since Nenad Vracar is agreeing with an upvoted answer. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with **Flexbox**, so if you add `flex: 1` to one child div it will take rest of free `width`

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50px;
}

.long {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Div 1</div>
  <div class="child">Div 2</div>
  <div class="child long">Div 3</div>
  <div class="child">Div 4</div>
</div>
```

Or you can use **CSS Table** with `table-layout: fixed` here is [`Browser support`](http://caniuse.com/#search=table)

```css
.parent {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50px;
}

.long {
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Div 1</div>
  <div class="child">Div 2</div>
  <div class="child long">Div 3</div>
  <div class="child">Div 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your time and idea. very appreciated. waiting for timer to expire to accept the answer.

Comment: Okey sir, for me it is working but (BTW) poor internet explorer support as usual http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You were right sir for suggesting me to wait for other answers. `calc`  browser support is better http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc (with the combination of `display:table-cell` which is full green according to caniuse.com).  What do you think

Comment: If you need support for IE9, IE8 and less go for it.

Comment: Yes, sir I still need support for IE9 at least. Thanks again

Comment: @whiteletters in blankpapers i updated my answer so take a look.

Comment: Thank you very much for  bringing your answer to the most fine and pure state. This is what I am using now and passing from `display:table`+`display:table-cell`, to `flexbox` to `calc` to `table-layout: fixed;` was very informative..

Answer (score 1):

#### For IE9+

You can use `inline-block` and `calc()` for this.

#### Snippet

```css
body {
 margin:0
}  
.parent {
  border:solid black;
  font-size:0; /*fix inline-block gap*/
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
  width:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:16px /*restore font -size*/
}

.calc{
  width: calc(100% - 348px)
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">one</div>
  <div class="child">two</div>
  <div class="child calc">three</div>
  <div class="child">four</div>
</div>
```

#### For IE8+

you can use `display:table/table-cell`

### Snippet

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
.parent {
  border: solid black;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  /*optional*/
  border-collapse:separate;
  border-spacing:5px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.child {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  display:table-cell;
}
.big {
  width:100%
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">one</div>
  <div class="child">two</div>
  <div class="child big">three</div>
  <div class="child">four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes sir, and thank you very much for your time regarding this issue.

Comment: just to remind this will work in IE9+, and please don't call me sir `:)`

Comment: Exactly sir, that is what I mentionned to Nenad Vracar in a comment. Again, thanks very much. I also think that I will be using `inline-block` from  your answer to replace the `float:left`

Comment: Updated my answer, take a look